# Is there an API to the Visual Studio class diagram graphical components?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, api, class-diagram

official or unofficial.
I've been digging around the VS assemblies with Reflector, with no success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, download the VS SDK.

Comment: @3D-Grabber: IIRC the VS2008 one has a C# sample for that.